# Impact of selection method for predicting random events

Tags: probability

So I had this thought experiment in mind where a finite number of random events are being conducted and your goal is to correctly predict as many as possible. For the sake of easier example, lets say that the random event is a fair coin flip and that the finite number is a nice number like 100, 1000, 1000000, etc. Now there are more ways to make your prediction then I will list but I have chosen four of them.

1. Predict that all of the coin flips will be the same face (e.g. predict that all will be heads)
2. Predict that half will be heads and half will be tails in whatever order you wish.
3. Predict simply by guessing
4. Predict by flipping a coin (e.g flip a coin, if heads, guess that the given flip will be heads as well)

I haven't been able to prove to myself that these 4 methods or any other you could come up with predict the same, better, or worse than the other.

Comment: In order to decide that, you'd first have to define what you mean by "better" or "worse".

Comment: better or worse meaning that if one predicts more coin tosses correctly than the other its better and if it predicts less coin tosses correctly than its worse. I am trying to avoid using words that have formal mathematical definitions because I only have a rudimentary understanding of probability.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever method you use for guessing, for each flip the probability that you guess it correctly is $\frac12$. Thus the expected number of correct predictions is half the number of flips, independent of the method of guessing.

Comment: How do you calculate the probability that you guess correctly ? On an individual flip you can just translate each statement into an equivalent probability. Like for my #1-#3 each individual flip is equivalent to what is the probability the coin will be a given face. (1/2)  With my #4 method an individual flip is equivalent to the probability of two coins being flipped having the same face (1/2). But how do you calculate it over a sequence of many flips ?

Comment: @user1086516: I don't understand the question "But how do you calculate it over a sequence of many flips?". You correctly found that the probability is $\frac12$ in each case; this is true independent of the number of flips. It's also true independent of the method of guessing, since whatever method you use, it results in some guess, and whatever that guess is, the flip has probability $\frac12$ to correspond and $\frac12$ not to correspond to the guess.